# Can poly1305 be used as an error-correction code?

Tags: mac, poly1305

Given a message $m$ of size $n$, a key $k$, and a message authentication code $mac = poly1305(m, k)$ what is the minimum amount of bitflips on the message that can be corrected (or at least detected) by someone who knows the corrupt message, the mac code, and the key?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2002/corr2002-19.ps and https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c561/1745cf0df38fb48a84b1d1481b8df0de53da.pdf suggest some MACs which they claim to be usable for error correction.

Comment: These error-correcting MACs make me nervous. The first acknowledges a reduction of security compared to the standard way (an error-correcting code at the line level, and a MAC on top of that); it also admits being impractical for large messages, since the error-correction requires a DLOG. The second gives a security proof (5.1) of information-theoretic nature; actual security is that of the associated stream cipher, which is required to make the scheme a true MAC (much like Carter-Wegman is not a MAC all by itself). This is not clear enough in the abstract IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is the minimum amount of bitflips on the message that can be corrected

Zero bits, Poly1305 doesn't provide error correction (at least Bernstein doesn't claim that property in the original paper).

> (or at least detected) by someone who knows the corrupt message, the mac code, and the key?

One bitflip is already detectable, it will change all bits of the resulting hash with a 0.5 chance.

Of course, there is always a negligible chance that the data does result in the correct hash (a chance of 1 in $2^{128}$ for the full MAC output). However, that's not dependent on how many bits are flipped.

Generally, it is recommended to keep the full output of the MAC calculation as an authentication tag.

---

If you also want error correction against changes, you could include a block of error-correcting code over the message + authentication tag. That way both are protected against non-malicious changes. Or you could use a specialized MAC algorithm as indicated [within your own comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/76155/8321992485).

---

Personally I don't see a direct way to **add** error correction capabilities to the Poly1305 calculations, but I'm not the best person to indicate if that's possible.